# Why does my python for loop only takes the last value of the loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I'm currently working on a script in python
In this part of the script i want to make a loop to get the mean peak value in each window.

```
df_window['Phasic_mean'] = 0
for a in range(1,len(df_window)-1):
    Phasic_mean = np.mean(df_window['Data'][a][0]/df_window_EDA['Data'][a][0])
```

With the loop above, I only get the last value (from the last window). Can someone help me to make the loop so that I get the value of each window in a dataframe.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Phasic_mean is overwritten at every iteration with the np.mean() value. Thus, at the end of the loop, Phasic_mean contains the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you collect the calculation result into a data structure. see `means` below

```
menas = []
df_window['Phasic_mean'] = 0
for a in range(1,len(df_window)-1):
    means.append(np.mean(df_window['Data'][a][0]/df_window_EDA['Data'][a][0]))
```

Comment: It worked out with your answer. Thankyou very much!